# А по-моему(,) – хороший

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова

Можете сказать, нужна ли эта запятая таки?

• По-его, этот котёнок нехороший, **а по-моему(,) —** хороший.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я считаю, что запятая таки не нужна:
*По-его, этот котёнок нехороший, **а по-моему*** [этот котёнок] ***—** хороший.*

> **10.** Тире при вводных словах (сочетаниях) употребляется в следующих случаях:
> **1)** если вводное сочетание образует неполную конструкцию (пропущено какое-либо слово, восстанавливаемое из контекста), то оно выделяется **запятой** и **тире**: *Макаренко неоднократно подчёркивал, что педагогика основана, **с одной стороны,** на безграничном доверии к человеку, **а с другой —** на высоких к нему требованиях*...

Разбираемся. Запятая и тире (это не комплексный знак) ставятся не после вводного сочетания, а таким образом: запятая ставится **перед** вводной конструкцией, а тире — **после**.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
***А по-моему —** так полчаса, не больше...* (В. Белоусова);
*Вы взгляните в окно... По-вашему, переменная облачность, **а по-моему —** ливень... Я хочу знать, когда он закончится...* (А. Вампилов).

Иногда, в зависимости от контекста, применяется авторское решение: вводные конструкции отделяются тире.

Сергей Романов. Парламент:

> — Это что за изобретение?
> — По-ихнему — кальвадос, по-нашему — яблочная водка, **а по-моему —** хоттабовка. Фрукты-то из моего сада.

Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие. Град обреченный:

> — Андрей, — сказал Кэнси. — Это же дезертирство.
> — По-твоему — дезертирство, **а по-моему —** разумный маневр.

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121) (Розенталь)